# Java- random spawning of rectangles

Tags: java, user-interface, random, rect

Here's just part of my code which doesn't work as I want.When rectangle which is in loop is painted, it's every time painted at the same place, despite the fact I used random number for X and Y axis.I would like to paint rectangle 5 times (as it's set in loop) and each on random coords.If whole code is necessary, let me know please.Thank you!

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    random=new Random();
    rX=random.nextInt(500);
    rY=random.nextInt(500);
    super.paintComponent(g);    

        for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        g.fillRect(rX,rY,20,20);
        }


    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);

}
```

Comment: You're currently painting the rectangle *six* times rather than five... but why are you doing that anyway? You're painting it in the same place all six times. What do you expect that to achieve? Note that you're only going to see a difference when `paintComponent` is called, which may be less than 100% predictable to the user.

Comment: That was my issue, that all rectangles are painted at the same place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your code only generates the coordinates only one time.
(Thanks to Jon Skeet for pointing it out)

If you want it to paint five different trianlges you should move the call to `random.nextInt` inside the loop.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    random=new Random();

    super.paintComponent(g);    

    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
        rX=random.nextInt(500);
        rY=random.nextInt(500);
        g.fillRect(rX,rY,20,20);
    }


    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);

}
```

Comment: This would draw 6 random rectangles on every repaint, rather than 1 rectangle at 5 random locations (that's how I understood the question). Still, this is more correct than the original code, so +1

Comment: @Heuster You are correct.  I guess that the original intent is not to paint different rectangles on every repaint, but rather generate them on some event/specified point.

Comment: Note that unless `random`, `rX` and `rY` are used elsewhere, they'd probably be better as local variables... although `random` could be an instance variable initialized *once*.